# image floating to the right...CSS

Tags: css

I wanted to positionate my images like this image below but it is not working properly.
[image]

**html**

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class='photo'><img src="http://img.pixland.uz/u2012f111790m.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
    <li class='photo'>
    <img src="http://img.pixland.uz/u13301f281573m.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**my css**

```
.navigate{
  background:#fff;
  color: #444;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav ul{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
}

.photo{
  float:right;
}
```

[**my code at JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/4/)

Comment: In your fiddle drag the window so it gets wider, your images will be positionned as you need them to.

Comment: hi, hat you need is inline-block + float http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/5/ no floats

Comment: @eb-tiki no it is not working!!!

Comment: oups, just realize i meant to right inline-block + white-space, not float.